# Multiple images display (slideshow) on wpInstalling Page under ProgressGauge bar in Inno Setup

Tags: image, slideshow, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have prepared simple script that displays image under `ProgressGauge` bar on `wpInstalling` Page.

But... I need more complex functionality.

What I need is multiple images show, each after X (e.g. 7) seconds (with loop when installation longer then X secs * number of images) or each after X (e.g. 10) percent of installation. I have tried to embed images display in `ProgressGauge.Position`, but I failed.

Here is what I have:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  BmpFile: TBitmapImage;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('01.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('02.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('03.bmp');

  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
  begin
    BmpFile:= TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
    BmpFile.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\01.bmp'));
    BmpFile.Width:= ScaleX(420);
    BmpFile.Height:= ScaleY(180);
    BmpFile.Left := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left + ScaleX(0); 
    BmpFile.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top + ScaleY(35);
    
    // BmpFile.Parent:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;
    // BmpFile:= TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
    // BmpFile.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\03.bmp'));
    // BmpFile.Width:= ScaleX(420);
    // BmpFile.Height:= ScaleY(400);
    // BmpFile.Left := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left + ScaleX(0); 
    // BmpFile.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top + ScaleY(35);
    // BmpFile.Parent:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;  
      
    // BmpFile:= TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
    // BmpFile.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\03.bmp'));
    // BmpFile.Width:= ScaleX(420);
    // BmpFile.Height:= ScaleY(400);
    // BmpFile.Left := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left + ScaleX(0); 
    // BmpFile.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top + ScaleY(35);
    // BmpFile.Parent:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;
  end;
end;
```

The goal is:
On the `wpInstalling` there should be X images displayed, every next per X seconds or after X percent of installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the [`ProgressGauge`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TNewProgressBar) has no progress change events and there is no way to process setup application messages you will need to use the Windows API timer. This timer needs a callback function which you can't define in Inno Setup script unfortunately so you will need some external library to do this job for you. However there's the [`InnoCallback`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=55) library which can do exactly this.

For the following code copy the [`InnoCallback.dll`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/file.php?id=21) library into your setup directory, merge this code with your Inno Setup script and implement some kind of a slideshow page turning in the `OnSlideTimer` event which will be called periodically (with the current settings each second).

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "InnoCallback.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy

[code]
var
  TimerID: Integer;

type
  TTimerProc = procedure(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; TimerID: UINT_PTR; 
    SysTime: DWORD);

function WrapTimerProc(Callback: TTimerProc; ParamCount: Integer): LongWord;
  external 'wrapcallback@files:InnoCallback.dll stdcall';    
function SetTimer(hWnd: HWND; nIDEvent, uElapse: UINT;
  lpTimerFunc: UINT): UINT; external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: HWND; uIDEvent: UINT): BOOL; 
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall'; 

procedure OnSlideTimer(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; TimerID: UINT_PTR; 
  SysTime: DWORD);
begin
  { here you can turn your slideshow pages; use some variable to store the }
  { current index of the slide you are on, note that this procedure is called }
  { periodically each 1000 ms (see below why), so here you can also check the }
  { progress value, if you want to }
end;

procedure StartSlideTimer;
var
  TimerCallback: LongWord;
begin
  TimerCallback := WrapTimerProc(@OnSlideTimer, 4);
  { third parameter here is the timer's timeout value in milliseconds }
  TimerID := SetTimer(0, 0, 1000, TimerCallback);
end;

procedure KillSlideTimer;
begin
  if TimerID <> 0 then 
  begin
    if KillTimer(0, TimerID) then
      TimerID := 0;
  end;
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  TimerID := 0;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  KillSlideTimer;
end; 

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
    StartSlideTimer
  else
    KillSlideTimer;
end;
```

Comment: As of now, one can use built-in [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback) instead of using external `WrapTimerProc` from `InnoCallback.dll`. For an example see [How to animate a control roll out in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47613550/850848).