# Inno Setup InnoCallBack.dll error

Tags: dll, slideshow, inno-setup

I have made a running script using innocallback.dll then i imported it to the graphical installer and it is also using the same dll and now i have an error 
"Exception: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
 Can I run the script using innocallback.dll twice? i have used this example then import it to graphical installer and the problem came.

[Inno Setup - Multiple Images display (slideshow) on wpInstalling Page under ProgressGauge bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130184/inno-setup-multiple-images-display-slideshow-on-wpinstalling-page-under-prog)

Comment: Ask [`vendor`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/765955/slappy) for this. He's responsible for running that another process. You can only rename the library and import it under the different name. Anyway, nice note [`in manual`](http://graphical-installer.com/files/manuals/inno/index.html), `botva2.dll`, `Source: Unknown`. Let's take an unknown, undocumented library from some russian forum and sell it with commercial product. Interesting strategy :-)

Comment: As first try to rename the library and use it that way as TLama said. If it does not work contact me (please send link to sources).

Comment: TLama/Slappy - I will try thanks for the quick reply...

Comment: it works... i just rename the other one innocallback2.dll and no error thanks again simple solution to big error... thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, I knew it will work, because the `LoadLibrary` function cares only about the file which is passed by name to its parameter. By this file name it then loads the library into an address space and returns a unique module handle which can be shared. However, in this case that another process didn't allow to share it...

Comment: thanks again, i learned a lot just viewing all your post and answer to all the question.