# Inno setup : How to set timers in between images slide show?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

i Was Created one setup for slide show code is perfectly running as you given. But the images are flipping with in short span of time. So in between images i want to set timer so that i can able to see those images clearly. Is that possible ? if possible how to do please help me to do that
    [code]

```
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
ExtractTemporaryFile('01.bmp'); 
ExtractTemporaryFile('02.bmp'); 
Result := True;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
BmpFile1, BmpFile2: TBitmapImage;
begin
if CurPageID = wpInstalling then begin 
msgbox ('1. where are you' , mbinformation,mb_ok);
  BmpFile1:= TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  BmpFile1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\01.bmp'));
  BmpFile1.Width:= ScaleX(976);
// here you set Width (417px is Width of ProgressBar) for 1st BMP
  BmpFile1.Height:= ScaleY(80);
// here you set Height for 1st BMP
  BmpFile1.Stretch := True;
  BmpFile1.Left := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left + ScaleX(0); 
  // here you set Left position for 1st BMP
  BmpFile1.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top + ScaleY(35);
  // here you set Top posision for 1st BMP
  BmpFile1.Parent:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;
  BmpFile2:= TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  BmpFile2.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\02.bmp'));
  BmpFile2.Width:= ScaleX(976);
  BmpFile2.Height:= ScaleY(80);
  BmpFile2.Stretch := True;
  BmpFile2.Left := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left + ScaleX(0); 
  BmpFile2.Top := BmpFile1.Top + BmpFile1.Height + ScaleY(8);
  BmpFile2.Parent:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;
  end;
  end;
```

Comment: If you want you can  modify my code to set timers.. can any one help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130184/inno-setup-multiple-images-display-slideshow-on-wpinstalling-page-under-prog).   
Please see also [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092779/how-to-show-percent-done-elapsed-time-and-estimated-time-progress/20092780#20092780) as it is possible to display Images without timer but with `CurInstallProgressChanged` function.